# Condensing (adding) multiple y values for each x value in R?

Tags: r, addition

I have a data frame with multiple y values for each x value. I'd like to create a new data frame from this one that only has one row for each x value, adding together all of the values for y and z that are associated with each x.

```
x   y   z
0   0   0
0   1   0
0   0   0
1   2   0
1   0   1
1   0   1
2   0   2
2   1   1
2   2   0
2   0   2
3   1   2
3   1   3
```

This is what I want the result to look like:

```
x   y   z
0   1   0
1   2   2
2   3   5
3   2   5
```

Is it possible to do this using cumsum, somehow conditionally on x? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `aggregate` from `base R` to group by 'x' and get the `sum` of other columns

```
aggregate(.~ x, df1, sum)
#  x y z
#1 0 1 0
#2 1 2 2
#3 2 3 5
#4 3 2 5
```